# how to add user programatically without interfering with cas module?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization, users

I have created a module that bulk create user entities depending on ldap filters and assign selected roles .
The problem is the connection with cas is then not working when a user entry has been already created

here is my code so far:

```
<?php /**
* @file
* Contains \Drupal\example\Form\ExampleForm.
*/

namespace Drupal\my_import_ldap\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
* Implements an example form.
*/
class MyImportLdapSettingsForm extends FormBase {

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getFormId() {

return 'my_ldap_import_settings_form';
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


    $system_roles = user_role_names(TRUE);


    $form['ldap_filter'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => $this->t('LDAP Filter'),
        '#description' => t('Specify LDAP filter used to populate Drupal user account'),
    );

    $form['actions2']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions2']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Save Filter'),
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );

    $form['roles_list'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#title' => $this->t('Rôles'),
        '#description' => t('Select the roles to assign created account'),
        '#options' => $system_roles,
    );


$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';

$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => $this->t('Import to Drupal People'),
'#button_type' => 'primary',

);
return $form;
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @author m.Dandonneau
 *
 *
 * add or update users, corresponding to the LDAP filters and add the selected roles
 *
*/
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if ($_POST['op']== 'Import to Drupal People'){

        $filter = $form_state->getValue('ldap_filter');
        $roles =$form_state->getValue('roles_list');
        $selected_roles=array();
        foreach($roles as $key => $value)
        {
            if(is_string($value))
            {
               $selected_roles[]=$value;
            }
        }

        //retrieve ldap settings yml from my_ldap module
        $my_ldap_config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('my_ldap.config_settings');
        $restrictions = explode(",", $my_ldap_config->get('my_ldap_restrictions'));
        $server = $my_ldap_config->get('my_ldap_server');
        $port = $my_ldap_config->get('my_ldap_port');
        $dn = $my_ldap_config->get('my_ldap_dn');
        $rootdn = $my_ldap_config->get('my_ldap_root_dn');
        $rootpw = $my_ldap_config->get('my_ldap_root_pwd');


        $attributes = array();
        $ds = ldap_connect($server, $port);
        if ($ds) {
            $r = ldap_bind($ds, $rootdn, $rootpw);
            $sr = ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $restrictions);
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

            $selected_users=array();
            if ($info["count"] > 0) {
                for($i=0;$i<$info["count"];$i++)
                {
                    $account=$this->create_update_drupal_user_account($info[$i]["uid"][0],$info[$i]["mymail"][0],$selected_roles);
                    $this->set_cas_user_name($account,$info[$i]["cn"][0]);
                    $selected_users[] = $info[$i]["uid"][0];
                }
                drupal_set_message($this->t('@selected_users ont été ajoutées ou updatées aux utilisateurs avec le(s) roles @selected_roles', array('@selected_users' => json_encode($selected_users),'@selected_roles' => json_encode($selected_roles))));
                \Drupal::logger('my_import_ldap')->notice($this->t('les personnes aux uids suivants @selected_users ont été ajoutées ou updatées avec le(s) roles @selected_roles', array('@selected_users' => json_encode($selected_users),'@selected_roles' => json_encode($selected_roles))));

            }
            else{
                drupal_set_message($this->t("le filtre LDAP @filtre n'a retourné aucun utilisateur", array('@filtre' => $form_state->getValue('ldap_filter'))));
                \Drupal::logger('my_import_ldap')->error($this->t("le filtre LDAP @filtre n'a retourné aucun utilisateur", array('@filtre' => $form_state->getValue('ldap_filter'))));
            }
        }
    }

    if ($_POST['op']== 'Save Filter')
        drupal_set_message($this->t('update filter', array('@number' => $form_state->getValue('ldap_filter'))));

}


   public function create_update_drupal_user_account($user_name,$user_mail,$roles){

       $lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

       $uid = \Drupal::entityQuery('user')
           ->condition('name', $user_name)
           ->execute();

       if(!empty($uid)){
           $uid=(int)reset($uid);
           $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($uid);
       }




       if (!$user) {
           $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
           //table structure is UNIQUE KEY `user__name` (`name`,`langcode`)
           $user->setUsername($user_name);
           $user->set("langcode", $lang);
           $user->enforceIsNew();
           $user->setEmail($user_mail);
          /*$user->setPassword(user_password());*/

       }

        foreach ($roles as $role)
            $user->addRole($role);

       $user->activate();
        $result = $user->save();


        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * @param $account
     */
    public function set_cas_user_name($account,$ldap_common_name){

        $lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
        $uid=$account->get('uid')->getValue()[0];

        $db = \Drupal::database();
        $query=$db->insert('user__field_cn_ldap')->fields(
            array(
                'bundle' => 'user',
                'entity_id' => $uid['value'],
                'revision_id' => $uid['value'],
                'langcode' => 'en',
                'delta' => 0,
                'field_cn_ldap_value' => $ldap_common_name,
            )
        )->execute();


         $cas_user_manager = \Drupal::service('cas.user_manager');
         $cas_user_manager->setCasUsernameForAccount($account, '$ldap_common_name');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my cas common name was wrong cause it is not the same as the ldap common name, here is the lines i have changed to make it work:

```
 $this->set_cas_user_name($account,$info[$i]["cn"][0],$info[$i]["uid"][0]);

 public function set_cas_user_name($account,$ldap_common_name,$cas_common_name){

 $cas_user_manager->setCasUsernameForAccount($account, $cas_common_name);
```